# A bash script to split a data file into many sub-files as per an index file using dd

Tags: bash, file, split, dd

I have a large data file that contains many joint files.
It has an separate index file has that file name, start + end byte of each file within the data file.
I'm needing help in creating a bash script to split the large file into it's 1000's of sub files.

Data File : fileafilebfilec etc

Index File:

filename.png<0>3049

folder\filename2.png<3049>6136.

I guess this needs to loop through each line of the index file, then using dd to extract the relevant bytes into a file. Maybe a fiddly part might be the folder structure bracket being windows style rather than linux style.

Any help much appreciated.

```
while read p; do

  q=${p#*<}
  startbyte=${q%>*}
  endbyte=${q#*>}
  filename=${p%<*}
  count=$(($endbyte - $startbyte))


toprint="processing $filename startbyte: $startbyte endbyte: $endbyte count: $c$
echo $toprint

done <indexfile
```

Comment: So far:
while read p; do
  echo $p
  q=${p#*<}
  startbyte=${q%>*}
  endbyte=${q#*>}
  filename=${p%<*}

toprint="processing $filename startbyte: $startbyte endbyte: $endbyte"
echo $toprint

done <indexfile

Comment: Put the code in the question, code in comments is terrible!

Comment: Thanks Nic3500, done

Answer (score 0):

Worked it out :-) FYI:

```
while read p; do

#sort out variables
  q=${p#*<}
  startbyte=${q%>*}
  endbyte=${q#*>}
  filename=${p%<*}
  count=$(($endbyte - $startbyte))


#let it know we're working
toprint="processing $filename startbyte: $startbyte endbyte: $endbyte count: $c$
echo $toprint

if [[ $filename == *"/"* ]]; then
  echo "have found /"


directory=${filename%/*}


#if no directory exists, create it
if [ ! -d "$directory" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $directory doesn't exist.
echo "directory not found - creating one"
mkdir ~/etg/$directory
fi

fi

dd skip=$startbyte count=$count if=~/etg/largefile of=~/etg/$filename bs=1

done <indexfile
```